# how to eliminate odd numbers from Date-picker days equation

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I would like to calculate the total days between start date and end date with using jquery date-picker.

I have searched it a lot and mostly the written solution for that was:

```
function calcDaysBetween(startDate, endDate) {
    return (endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

that works  but between some dates I get results like:(total days= 0.9583333333333334)

For exp: if you choose start: March 30. and end: April 30 then result is 30.958333333333332
check it here please:
http://jsfiddle.net/9EZXx/6/

How can I solve that?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange.. when I run the fiddle I get 31 days as the result. You can probably just use parseInt and Math.round to get the right answer:

```
function calcDaysBetween(startDate, endDate) {
    return parseInt(Math.round((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
}
```

Comment: As you add parseInt you get 31 indeed! Thanx a lot!